# My celery task never returns

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am just starting to learn about Django and have just discovered celery to run async background tasks.

I have a dummy project which I pilfered off the internet with a sample task as follows:

```
from djcelery import celery
from time import sleep      

@celery.task
def sleeptask(i):
    sleep(i)
    return i
```

Now in my view, I have the following:

```
def test_celery(request):
    result = tasks.sleeptask.delay(10)
    return HttpResponse(result.task_id)
```

This runs fine and when I point the browser to it, I get some random string like `93463e9e-d8f5-46b2-8544-8d4b70108b0d` which I am guessing is the task id.

However, when I do this:

```
def test_celery(request):
    result = tasks.sleeptask.delay(10)
    return HttpResponse(result.get())
```

The web browser goes in a loop with the message "Connecting..." and never returns. I was under the impression, this will block till the task is run and give the result but that does not seem to be the case. What am I doing wrong?

Another question is the way I am doing it, is it going to run it asynchronously i.e. not block while the task is running?

**EDIT**

In my `settings.py` file I have:

```
import djcelery
# Setup celery
djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

On the Django side, I do not get any errors:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 27, 2016 - 18:13:12
Django version 1.9.5, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Comment: You're running a worker, right?  If so, are you also running a results backend?

Comment: hmmmmm... I am not sure what you mean. I just followed some example on the web. Installed redis and basically tried to run this simple task. Would it help if I post celery specific commands in my `settings.py` file?

Comment: do you have results backend properly configured? what is printing the "connecting"? do you get some error message on the worker log?

Using `.get()` will block in this case

Comment: I did not do any `redis` configuration beyond what is in the settings file. Running `redis-cli PING` works as expected.

Comment: I'm believing your command to call celery could be missing something. According to this [post](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3759#issuecomment-311763355), you may need to add `-P solo` to your command like: 
`celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency 1 -P solo`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hints in the comments, I finally was able to solve the problem. I had to add the following:

`CELERY_IMPORTS('myproject.tasks')` to my settings.py file.

I also needed to run the worker as:

```
python manage.py celery worker
```